# How can I insert text inside the aligned environment?

Tags: align

I often need to insert text and breaks in between equations but it's too cumbersome to type aligned again from beginning. What can I do to insert text inside the aligned environment ?

Also, is there any difference between align and aligned ? The former gives compile errors on my computer .

Comment: Here is useful link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49541/10898

Comment: @azetina Can I do this with aligned since I'm facing problems with align ?

Comment: I believe so. Give it a try.

Comment: @azetina Intertext doesn't work well with aligned. What do you think is a good way of writing proofs where explanations are require in between equations ? But, at the same time there has to be some continuity like alignment.

Comment: Could you post waht you've tried? The difference between `align` and `aligned` is the latter has to be used when you're already in math mode (e.g. àligned` inside `gather` or `$\begin{aligned}…\end{aligned}$` for inline maths).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't detailed enough to give a good answer,  the OP hasn't been here for years, and the answer is not good (and has no votes).

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\sqrt{|a_{11} + b_{11} + \dots a_{nn} + a_{nn}|} & \leq \sqrt{|a_{11} + \dots + a_{nn}|} + \sqrt{|b_{11} + \dots + b_{nn}|}\\
 x &= \sqrt{|a_{11} + b_{11} + \dots a_{nn} + a_{nn}|} \notag\\ 
 y &= \sqrt{|a_{11} + \dots + a_{nn}|} \notag\\
 z &= \sqrt{|b_{11} + \dots + b_{nn}|}\notag\\
x & \leq  y + z  \notag\\
&= Square~{} each~{} element ~{}x, ~{}y ~{}and~{} z~{}and ~{} compute
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: formula]

Comment: Can you explain why you wrote ~{} so many times in the last line ?

Comment: Also, can you do it with aligned ? I'm getting compile errors with align.

Comment: I figured out the error ! Align, unlike aligned should not be preceded by dollar signs ! Thanks ! Now, can you give some other options on how to insert text like Intertext or something ?

Comment: that last line could be written better as `&= \text{Square each element x, y and z and computer}` Also, `mathtools` improves upon `amsmath`

Comment: Thanks. the last line could be written by using \text command also.

Comment: @murugan I think it *should* be written with `\text`, though I would say `\text{Square each element $x$, $y$ and $z$ and compute}`. The words  *Square each element..` are just that, words, they're not mathematical constructs, and should be treated thereafter.

Comment: I agree. User wanted that as a second step and in mathematical format /()^2. This would be difficult to understand for any common man. So I gave it in the text form within align environment.